# NVCC unistd.h(792): error: expected an identifier

Tags: cuda, linker, nvcc, unistd.h

NVCC is returning an error but with little information to go on. The project did compile before moving to so called 'modern cmake'. I no longer use findCUDA. I've done multiple web searches and can't find a trail to take to help resolve the issue.
Any help would be great. thanks.

```
[  3%] Building CUDA object CMakeFiles/foo_cuda.dir/src/foo/gpu/gpu_camera.cu.o
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc  -DFOO_DATA_DIR=\"/home/developer/Data\" -DFOO_RESULTS_DIR=\"/home/developer/Results\" -DBAR_GFLAGS_NAMESPACE=google -DBAR_SUITESPARSE_VERSION=\"5.1.2\" -D__CUDACC__ -I/home/developer/Source/Foo/include -I/home/developer/Source/Foo/src -I/home/developer/Source/Foo -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/developer/Source/Foo/SYSTEM -I/usr/include/eigen3  -g -Xcompiler=-fPIC   -w -std=c++14 -Xcompiler=-fopenmp -use_fast_math -Wno-deprecated-declarations --expt-extended-lambda --expt-relaxed-constexpr -dc -Dlink -lcudart -lcudrand -lcudadevrt -lcublas -lcublas_device -gencode arch=compute_30,code=compute_30 -x cu -dc /home/developer/Source/Foo/src/foo/gpu/gpu_camera.cu -o CMakeFiles/foo_cuda.dir/src/foo/gpu/gpu_camera.cu.o
/usr/include/unistd.h(792): error: expected an identifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the contents of line 792 of `/usr/include/unistd.h` would allow one to guess the answer better.

Usually this error results from *something* that you `#include` *before* `unistd.h` using a conflicting `#define`

For example, if line 792 of `unistd.h` reads:

```
extern int link (const char *__from, const char *__to);
```

and some previous header did this:

```
#define link 1
```

then the compiler will see (after preprocessing):

```
extern int 1 (const char *__from, const char *__to);
```

and will rightfully produce `error: expected an identifier`.

A useful way to diagnose these kinds of problems is to run the preprocessor *and* save values of all `#define`s. With GCC:

```
gcc -E -dD -I... foo.c > foo.e
```

Similar flags (`-E -dD`) may work for `nvcc`, or you may have to find something equivalent.

**Update:**

As Robert Crovella noted, you *actually* have `-Dlink` on your command line, so it's likely that your `unistd.h` matches mine, and `extern int 1 (const char ...` is *exactly* what your compiler sees after preprocessing.

Don't *do that*! That is, don't `#define` standard identifiers (either on command line, or anywhere else in your code).

Comment: with respect to `link`, the thing that could mess up a construct like that is this switch in the command line, which is odd/curious: `-Dlink`

Comment: @RobertCrovella I didn't scroll far enough in the command line to notice that. Thanks! Answer updated.

Comment: It was in fact '$<$<BUILD_INTERFACE:$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>>:-Dlink>' screwing up my life.

Thank you gentlemen for the help, hope this information helps out someone else too.